# How can I search GitHub pull requests?

Tags: github

I'm currently viewing a popular GitHub repo. Inside there are over 300 pull requests (100 open, 200 closed).

How can I search these pull requests to see if a particular topic already exists within them?

i.e. I don't want to create some code and submit a pull request if someone has already done a similar pull.

---

Edit: Alternatively - since I know what file(s) I plan on changing - is it possible to view a specific file on GitHub, and say "Hey. Are there any outstanding pull requests that relate to this specific file?".

---

Update: GitHub now offers this easily - when browsing a repository the search bar at the top offers to search only the select repo - which makes it much easier to search for what you need.

Comment: Regarding your edit: Are there any outstanding pull requests that relate to this specific file, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/26377055/6309

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Update

Now, the main search bar is used for all searches. You can filter by code/repos/issues/etc on the left. To see pull requests, click the `Issues` filter.

[image: search image]

Answer (score 8):

You can find this search form on Issues tab:
[image]

Comment: It searches for both issues and pull request. And I think you can't find a pull request fir a specific file, sorry.

Comment: thanks! (I deleted my previous comment when I realised you are correct)

Answer (score 5):

I add these informations if it can help someone who finds this discussion via a search engine. You can use GitHub filters.

Search all pull requests: `is:pr`

Search all open pull requests: `is:pr is:open`

Search all open pull requests by user: `is:pr is:open author:username`

Search all open pull requests commented by user: `is:pr is:open commenter:username`

I did not see the `commenter` filter documented somewhere or available in the advanced search, I just found it by guessing and it worked.

If you want to search all pull requests talking about a specific feature, you can just add the keyword to the search.

Answer (score 3):

Github repo activity search is now [very well documented](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-issues/).

e.g. `github commenter:defunkt type:issue`