# On Github, how do I find what pull requests individual file commits belong to

Tags: github

On GitHub, I can see the history of commits of a file under `.../commits/master/filename`. What I want to know is, assuming these changes were merged into `master` via Pull Requests, what Pull Request did the change come from? Is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: Do you look for github-only (site) solution, or any git-related tool / console will be ok?

Comment: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/104839/224355

Answer (score 0):

Since Oct. 13, 2014, this should be easier:

### [Linking merged pull requests from commits](https://github.com/blog/1905-linking-merged-pull-requests-from-commits)

> We've been [including the containing branches and tags on commit pages](https://github.com/blog/1451-branch-and-tag-labels-for-commit-pages) to give you more context around changes. Now, commits in a repository's default branch will also show you the pull request that introduced them.

[image: commit with PR reference in it!]

> In the pull request, you can see the discussion around why the commit was introduced, and get a clearer picture of the reason for the change.
>
> As always, if you know the commit SHA, you can skip the commit page and [search for the pull request directly](https://github.com/rails/rails/search?q=b32ba367f584a6298fb8b7eef97be15388b5bd87&ref=cmdform&type=Issues).

---

For instance:

You can see for the file [`hakimel/reveal.js/plugin/markdown/markdown.js`](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/commits/master/plugin/markdown/markdown.js), [my contribution](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/commit/f2097417daca80b2caaed2661ee646e861d789c8) now comes with a reference to the [PR #734](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/pull/734) it originated.

[image: PR from contrib]

---

Note however that:

- neither [GitHub Get single commit API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#get-a-single-commit), like https://api.github.com/repos/hakimel/reveal.js/commits/f2097417daca80b2caaed2661ee646e861d789c8
- nor [GitHub Get a commit API](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/commits/#get-a-commit), like https://api.github.com/repos/hakimel/reveal.js/git/commits/f2097417daca80b2caaed2661ee646e861d789c8

will include the reference to the PR...